# dynamic Google Map triggering the null object reference error

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to add a dynamic google map to a fragment, this fragment contains a simple form which is working ok, i am getting an error when i add the google map part.

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jdplee.proyecto/com.jdplee.proyecto.ClientDetailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.jdplee.proyecto.ClientDetailFragment com.jdplee.proyecto.ClientDetailFragment.newInstance()' on a null object reference

What i have is a `mainActivity` with a button that opens a detail view, this is done using a second Activity:

```
public class ClientDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int REQUEST_ADD_TASK = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.client_detail);


        ClientDetailFragment mClientDetailFragment = (ClientDetailFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.cd_fragment_container);

        if (mClientDetailFragment == null) {

            mClientDetailFragment = ClientDetailFragment.newInstance();


            utilities.addFragmentToActivity(getSupportFragmentManager(), mClientDetailFragment, R.id.cd_fragment_container);
        }
    }
}
```

the client_layout only has a FrameLayout where the fragment is going to be put, the fragment class is:

```
public class ClientDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

    public static ClientDetailFragment newInstance() {
        return new ClientDetailFragment();
    }

    public ClientDetailFragment(){
        //required empty constructor
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.client_detail_fragment, container, false);

        if (getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.cd_maplocation) == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();

            getChildFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.cd_maplocation, mapFragment)
                    .commit();
}

        return root;
    }
```

and this fragment has his layout which inside has the framelayout for the google map:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/cd_maplocation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

that is why i am using `getChildFragment()`, for me all this makes sense, i dont get why the error, am i missing something?

Comment: please provide logcat.

Comment: i did, the error in quote its from logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this thing on onActivityCreated()

```
if (getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.cd_maplocation) == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();

            getChildFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.cd_maplocation, mapFragment)
                    .commit();
    }
```

Comment: yes that worked, can you explain a bit about it? also this method is called when the activity that is creating and putting the fragment to the framelayout is created?

Comment: Please accept an answer if worked. You are having fragment (child)inside another fragment(parent) and your adding/replace child before parent fragment is initialize that was the problem.

Comment: if you edit your answer and complement it, that will be very helpful, i understand the fragment inside another fragment, that is why i am using `getChildFragment`

Comment: why `onActivityCreated` and not `onViewCreated` because i used that one first too and it didnt work